# How do I get a JSON request but get a certain part of it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this current Python code...

```
import requests
import json
response = json.loads(requests.get("https://meta.multimc.org/v1/net.minecraftforge/index.json").text)
```

But I can't find out how to get a specific bit instead of the whole JSON page.

I'd like to get versions.version on that URL but I can't find out what piece of code to add to make it do that.

Comment: You need to share the JSON you are trying to process.

Comment: Unless the server has an API to get only the specific part of the response that you want, your only option is to pull put the required part from the complete response.

Comment: @rdas, how do I do that?

Comment: Unrelated, but the response object has a `json()` method: `r = requests.get('...'); response = r.json()`

Comment: You've already loaded the response into a dictionary. You just need `response['versions']` & go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate over the versions array in `response['versions']` and add each version to a list.

```
import request
import json

response = json.loads(requests.get("https://meta.multimc.org/v1/net.minecraftforge/index.json").text)

versions=[]
for i in range(len(response['versions'])):
    versions.append(response['versions'][i]['version'])
```

Comment: Thanks! I removed the versions array and for for I in range thing and replaced it with
print(response['versions'][1]['version'])

Comment: Just waiting on the answer timer to run out then I'll mark as answer